# Create a year variable to establish a panel variable-

Tags: stata, variable-assignment, panel, panel-data

I have 3 variables in Stata that I want to make into a panel variable, `f4hi`. Currently, they are called `f4hi97`, `f4hi98`, and `f4hi99`. I want to pull the last two digits from these to create a separate year variable (1997, 1998, and 1999).

[The image shows the way I want the data to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x73g.png)

I have tried this command to reshape to panel, but it will not work without the year variable

```
reshape long f4hi97 f4hi98 f4hi99, i(id) j(year)
```

Ultimately, I want to be able to run this model:

```
xtreg f4hi99 f2s99d race sex byfaminc byt3_8, fe
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Your image helps, but nothing is as good as code that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your `xtreg` looks odd, but if this works, that's your next problem. If you have a question about panel regression, please start a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common error to supply `reshape long` with variable names. It needs stubnames. Also `j()` indicates a variable that will be created, not a variable in your dataset at present. You might try

```
reshape long f4hi, i(id) j(year)
replace year = 1900 + year
```